# Powershell: invoke-item not producing an error when it doesn't invoke and there is an asterisk involved

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script that will open documents, folders, urls etc.

I want to take advantage of `invoke-item` to accomplish this as it will handle any associations for me.

I am passing an expression to a function that will then attempt to open something like this:

```
Invoke-Item -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue $expression
if (! $?) {
    [void][System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Unable to open $expression")
}
```

In the case of a file that is malformed, I expect to get an error.

For example, this file does not exist, and the command

`invoke-item C:\temp\blahblah.txt`

results in error:  *PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeItemCommand*

I could then give a more specific error to the user (me).

My problem is that if I mistakenly pass in a file path that has an **asterisk** in the name, due to my fat-fingering of the input, then I get NO ERROR at all!

Example: The following file--nor any wildcarding variant of it--exists.

`invoke-item C:\temp\blahblah*.txt`

The `invoke-item` acts as if all is well and produces no error.

So, while most questions on StackOverflow are about how to avoid errors, I want to know: How can I produce one?!

Comment: It appears that's just the way PowerShell works. A wildcard search will complete successfully, even if it doesn't find anything that matches. So what do you want to do? Do you want to change PowerShell behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes walking away and coming back to a problem brings clarity.

Instead of getting `invoke-item` to error out, I just check for existence of the item before trying to invoke it

```
if (Test-Path $file) {
    invoke-item ...
}
else {
    error message here 
}
```

Now if there are extraneous characters including asterisk, the test-path fails.